# Examples of domain-specific monads in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads

I understand (more or less) *standard* monads such as `Option (Maybe)`, `List`, `State`, `Reader`, `Writer`, etc. They are *universal* and can be found in any application. Other examples of *universal* monads are iterator, stream, data collections, etc.

Now I would like to see *domain-specific* monads. One example is `Parser` monad. It is *not* as universal as `Option`, `List`, `State`, etc. since it encapsulates *domain specific* parsing logic.

What are other *domain specific* monads you can think of ?

Comment: I think many "domain-specific" monads provide just the combined behaviour of basic ones. For example, a parser is a `State` encapsuling nondeterminism by wrapping the resulting state/value pair in `List` or `Maybe` (have a look [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.1.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans.html)). So, maybe you just want _monad transformers_?

Comment: Grepping the source for projects like [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) and [scalaz-contrib](https://github.com/typelevel/scalaz-contrib) would be a good way to start. Some examples that might count as more "domain specific" include the [undo monad](https://github.com/typelevel/scalaz-contrib/tree/master/undo), [random number generators](https://github.com/NICTA/rng), etc.

Comment: @phg Thanks. Now I am thinking you are right. There are only few _basic_ monads  and all domain specific monadic computations are just a combinations of them.

Comment: @Michael: That's not really true, though. Consider for example [xmonad](http://xmonad.org/)'s `X`, [Hakyll](http://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/)'s compiler and routes, etc. These are all in a sense subsets of `IO`, but they're not just combinations of the basic ones you've mentioned.

Comment: @TravisBrown Thank you. Those `xmonad` and `hakyll` look like _truly_ great examples but they are too big and complicated. I would like to see something like them but smaller and simpler.

Comment: @Michael I'd argue that you can't really hope to understand any domain specific monad independently from the domain in which it is used, meaning that you probably won't find something "smaller and simpler".

Comment: @Michael Agreeing with Travis, I didn't mean to say that transformer stacks are all there is. They are just commonly found. Another important ground to build domain specific monads are free monads, for which the [operational](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/operational-0.2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Operational.html) package provides a nice "interface". Also, I want to point out [this](http://code.haskell.org/~byorgey/TMR/Issue15/Issue15.pdf#page=11) article, which discusses interesting, lesser known monads (with `Prompt` being almost equivalent to operational's `Program`).

Comment: @phg Thanks. Great reference !

Comment: I think probability monads like the Giry monad can count as somewhat domain specific. Also every algebra defines a monad, so if your domain can be described by an algebra, then there is a specific monad for it. I do not understand why this question was closed. It makes perfect sense to me I would have been interested to see the answers. Not sure why there would be to many answers (the cited reason for closing), given that none were actually given.  It looks like at least 11 other people would agree with me. Not sure why the question is specific to Scala though.